# DataContractSerializer - Ignore XML Declaration

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

How can I get the DataContractSerializer to ignore the xml declaration in xml I want to deserialize?

I want to avoid reading all bytes from stream and removing the declaration from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContractSerializer` will not serialize the XML declaration, as you do will not have a property for it on the class you are deserializing to.

Regardless - it needs to read the whole file, so the declaration will be read as well.

Why are you trying to remove it like this?

Comment: I'm only deserializing and don't have control over how it is serialized.  Any ideas?

Comment: @chief7 - I don't follow. The `DataContractSerializer` will product an XML declaration when _serializing_, but ignore it when _deserializing_, as it will not have a place to put it in your object.

Comment: I see now.  I was getting an error on deserialization about not finding the xml element it was expecting.  I assumed it was b/c of the xml declaration but it was caused by the wrong xml namespace which I have resolved.  Thanks!